# SQL Server split two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, split

I must import some data in our system and there is **a specific column** [FiscalInfo] that unfortunately holds **both** FiscalDepartment AND the FiscalNumber information. I want to split it into **two** columns:
[FiscalDepartment] AND the [FiscalNumber]

Here is a sample

```
[FiscalInfo]
F.O 885621791  F.D
F.O   F.D 
F.O 335064214  F.D KALOST
F.O  F.D ASRIT
```

from what you can see, I **do not always** have the info about F.O and F.D but **I always** have their abbreviations inside the column (F.O and F.D).

Is there a way to split the information?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very hardcoded to these specifics *(assuming the field always starts with 'F.O ' etc)*, but hopefully illustrates the point...

```
WITH cte as
(      select 'F.O   F.D' as ss
 UNION select 'F.O 885621791  F.D'
 UNION select 'F.O 335064214  F.D KALOST'
 UNION select 'F.O  F.D ASRIT '
)
select 
  substring(ss, 5, charindex('F.D',ss)-5) as FO,
  substring(ss, charindex('F.D',ss)+4, 8000) as FD
from cte
```